# Extraction Error "no such element: Unable to locate element: "

Tags: python, selenium

I am working on a project for extracting group id's from internal site.

The code reads urls which is in the groupid.csv file which is located in my desktop and extracts the groupid and writes in the excel sheet groupid.xlsx

The below code runs successfully until there are valid urls, but gives me an error if there is invalid urls (groupid.csv) and stops working.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time
import os

c=1

user = os.getlogin()
path = "C:/Users/"+user+"/Desktop/groupid.csv"
path1 = "C:/Users/"+user+"/Desktop/groupid.xlsx"
print(path)

reader = pd.read_csv(path)
driver =webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()

reader['groupid'] = ''
for line in reader['URL']:
    print(line)
    driver.get(line)
    if c==1:
        time.sleep(20)

    time.sleep(5)
    groupid = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@xpath"]').text
    print(groupid)
    reader['groupid'][reader['URL']==line] = groupid
    c=c+1    
reader.to_excel(path1)
```

Error code:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="xpath_ID"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)
```

please help me to come out of this error for successful extraction

Comment: So why don't you handle the error using a try catch block?

Comment: Since i am very beginner, i don't know where i should use try catch block

Comment: In Python, what @TarunLalwani is referring to is a `try except`. You can place `try except` blocks around specific parts of your code in order to gracefully continue if your code encounters an error. See this article about [Python Exceptions](https://realpython.com/python-exceptions/#the-try-and-except-block-handling-exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

If you know that there are some broken links try to add try catch blocks to handle it. An easy way could be something like this.

```
try:
  groupid = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@xpath"]').text
except:
  //CONTINUE WITH NEXT ONE
```

Comment: receiving an error:  "36: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  reader.to_excel(path1)"

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
 reader = pd.read_csv(path)
your remaining code
except:
  print("An exception occurred")
```

or You can use below code to check URLs are valid or not

```
import requests
request = requests.get(URL)
if request.status_code == 200:
    print('Web site exists')
else:
    print('Web site does not exist')
```